# Python- encode base64 print new line

Tags: python, base64, newline

I want to try to encrypt my python code with `base64`.
But when I use `\n` I get an error:

```
print("hello 
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

This is my code I used:

```
import base64

def encode(data):
    try:
        # Standard Base64 Encoding
        encodedBytes = base64.b64encode(data.encode("utf-8"))
        return str(encodedBytes, "utf-8")
    except:
        return ""
    
def decode(data):
    try:
        message_bytes = base64.b64decode(data)
        return message_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    except:
        return ""

your_code = encode("""
    print("hello \n world")

""")

exec(decode(your_code))
```

I could use twice the `print()` function instead of `\n` but is there a way to use `\n`?

I hope you can help me out

Comment: This has **nothing to do with** encoding or decoding. The code isn't valid because of the leading whitespace. Making the code into a string and `exec`ing it doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to remove the indent in the your_code section. Second you have to replace `\n` with `\\n`

```
import base64


def encode(data):
    try:
        # Standard Base64 Encoding
        encodedBytes = base64.b64encode(data.encode("utf-8"))
        return str(encodedBytes, "utf-8")
    except:
        return ""


def decode(data):
    try:
        message_bytes = base64.b64decode(data)
        return message_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    except:
        return ""


your_code = encode("""
print("hello \\n world")

""")

exec(decode(your_code))
```