# Ptython - how to write '\\n' to a file

Tags: python, newline

I need to write `\\n` into a file.
The problem I have is I get only `\n`

```
def read_file(input_path):
    f = open(input_path, "r")
    read_lines = f.readlines()
    read_lines_length = len(read_lines)
    r = 0 
    while r < read_lines_length:
        read_lines[r]= read_lines[r].replace('\n','')
        r+=1
    f.close()

    for element in range(len(read_lines)):
        read_lines[element].replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')

    return read_lines
```

With this I am able to store `\\n` in a List but when I use `f.write()` it only prints `\n`. Normally would you just make: `prin(\\\\n)` to get `\\n` but when I make `.replace("\n", "\\\\n")` it stays `\\n` in the List

```
['print("Enter: \'stop\' --> exit function.\\n"']
```

The Output:

```
read = read_file(input_path)
for element in range(len(read)):
    print(read[element])

---> print("Enter: 'stop' --> exit function.\n"
```

What I want to accomplish is a file which will create automatic from my `normal` Python file an `encrypted` python file.

Here some files to work with:

[Core.py](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#52ngae4nz256np3bg0g1a4)

[packager.py](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#kerd5i9xb0hh4ms6vux80g)

[what I want to have](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#vrsm5bd18cz476q4mja2r)

And here the folder Structure: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIkUK.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need that? You've given no context at all

Comment: Do you want to write backslash, backslash, n to the file or backslash, newline?

Comment: You want to write the literal string `\\n` to the file? No newlines or anything, just that literal string? Then use `"\\\\n"`.

Comment: just backslash, backslash, n

Comment: @MattDMo I tried: `.replace("\n", "\\\\n")` but in the List it stays `\\n`

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted...

Comment: @roganjosh I want to create automatic encrypted python files and in base64 I need `\\n` to write a new line

Comment: @MattDMo it is already `\\n` in the list but when I print it it's just `\n`

Comment: Encrypted files in base64?

Comment: So you're trying to write base64 manually? Why don't you use [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)?

Comment: @roganjosh [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643469/python-encode-base64-print-new-line)

Comment: @Muddyblackk then you should have been picked up right there. There is nothing _encrypted_ about this _at all_. It's just an encoding.

Comment: @roganjosh yes I had already changed some thing:
[snippet](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#3rungf300yvqxqzqv3maj)

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the CONTENTS of a string and the REPRESENTATION of a string.  If you type the line `s='\\n'` in Python, that string contains two characters: a backslash and an "n".  If you type `s`, Python will print `"\\n"` as the representation, even though there are NOT two backslashes.  If you `print(s)`, it will print `\n` with one backslash, no newline.  If you really want the three-characters "backslash backslash n" written to a file, you need to express that in a Python string as `"\\\\n"`.  That is a string with 3 characters in it.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes and the final problem for me is to replace `\n` with `\\\\n` in the List. I can only replace to `\\n` whatever how many backslashes I put in the replace function

Comment: Do you want to replace "newline", or do you want to replace the two-character string "backslash n"?  Are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is just the different view of text in the lists by `print` function. In fact the `\n` in list are really `\n` not `\\n`. Please pay attention to the following example. The `\n` is used between `Hello` and `World`, after `print(a)`, two words appear in different lines. In `b` variable `a` is inserted in the list (`[]`); now `print(b)` show `\n`.

```
a = "Hello\nWorld"
print(a)
b = [a]
print(b)
print(b[0])
```

The output:

```
Hello
World
['Hello\nWorld']
Hello
World
```

**Edit based on question changes:**

Changing `read_file` as the following code can help:

```
def read_file(input_path):
    f = open(input_path, "r")
    read_lines = f.readlines()
    read_lines = [r.replace("\\n",'\\\\n').replace('\n','') for r in read_lines] 
    f.close()
    return read_lines
```

Comment: I will look I think my filewriter is bad and shouldn't look for the length but for the String

Comment: I already edited it. It is where I say "what I want to accomplish"
And it was not my filewriter ;(

Comment: I want to write every element of the List into a new line of another fresh file.

Comment: Replacing `f.write(element)` in the write function with `f.write(element + "\n")` solve your problem?

Comment: No this would just add blank lines to my file. So here some examplefiles:  [Core.py](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#52ngae4nz256np3bg0g1a4) [packager.py](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#kerd5i9xb0hh4ms6vux80g) [what I want to have](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#vrsm5bd18cz476q4mja2r)

Comment: The Folder Structure: [imgur](https://imgur.com/D0OSFRW)

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: Uh nice now I see what you meant... well I learned something :D
But you should still let the rest of the function as it was otherways there will be added some unwanted lines to the endfile: [codesnippet](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#m1nk9ilq1y94nrqoiyydg)

Comment: Thanks. Base on your file the answer is edited :)